# Prestashop - VAT Number for guests and new accounts

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using Prestashop 1.6

I would to know if there is a way to make the VAT Number field appear in the "Guest check out" and "New account" forms, but without being required (because some countries doesn't have VAT Number).

I tried to remove "VAT Number" from some countries in the Localization tab in the dashboard, but it didn't change anything, so the solution is not there.

Thank you !

Comment: Have you also removed the vat number as required field in 'Customers > Addresses'? (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Actually, activate the vat number in Customers > Addresses is the only way to make it appear in the guest check out. It won't otherwise, unless you reload the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

In *your_shop/themes/default-bootstrap/order-opc-new-account.tpl*

Remove the following line :

***{elseif $field_name eq "vat_number"}***